# How can I extract images from the .resources file created by a decompile of a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources, decompiling

I am working on recovering the source for an application for a client of mine. I have managed to recover the application code using [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector). But now I want to neaten the code and recreate the individual forms so will that I have the codebehind, designer and resx files for each form. The problem is that all the images are located in ".resources" files. How do I extract the images from these ".resources" files that were generated by Reflector?

I would prefer to use some tool, rather than having to extract the images programmatically, but I will resort to code if I can't find a suitable application. So here I am hoping that someone has done this before or knows of a viewer (preferably free!) for these resources files that would allow me to extract the images. Otherwise, code is also good; as I could then write my own little application to extract the images.

Comment: Reflector can do this too, open the Resources node of an assembly.  Right-click the resource and select Save As.

Comment: I have tried to extract the images with Reflector, but as far as I can see, Reflector only saves the .resources file, it does not let you save the bitmaps contained in these files in BMP format... unless I am missing something? It does give a listing of the bitmaps when you select a .resources file, but when I right click on the bitmap, there is an option "save as" that is unfortunately grayed out. Maybe this is a feature in a paid version that is missing in the trial version that I am using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This program help you
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Extracting_Embedded_Image.aspx

Comment: Thanks, sepulka. I tested the program that you linked here and it works well. :) I also found this program which I used as well, http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2005/10/09/Resource-File-Extractor.aspx. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Unfortunately the codeproject solution does not recognize my built project as an assembly.  Clive Tong's answer worked for me.

Comment: +1 - The codeproject.com project is old (.NET 2.0 VS2008 PRK)- so make sure you update and recompile to the version of .NET you are using now.  Works perfect for me in VS2017 .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 30):

You can save the `.resources` file and then use the resgen tool (part of the VS2010 tools) to convert it back into a `.resx` file, using a command line like:

```
resgen foo.resources bar.resx
```

The `.resx` can then be added to a C# project. Once you've done this, if you try to open the individual images, VS2010 will offer to extract them into a standalone image file.

Comment: +1! The free [VS2013 community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is also able to open .resx files and extract stuff from it.

Answer (score 7):

**ILSpy** should do this job - see features at http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx and the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This only allows you to save the resources as a .resources file. As far as I can tell, it does not let you extract the bitmap images from the resources file.

Comment: Weird, the screenshot has a Save button for every bitmap

Comment: HI Poupou. Thanks for trying to help. Yeah, that screenshot is deceptive and makes it look like it can, but it actually doesn't let you save images that are contained in a _.resources_ file. In my case, if I select the _resources_ folder like in the screenshot, I get a list of resources files, like the first entry in the image. So in my case, none of the entries listed are actual BMP files, but resources files that contain the bitmaps. If I view the resources files in Reflector, I can see a listing of the bitmaps that each file contains, but cannot save these individual bitmaps to disk.

Answer (score -1):

JustDecompile can do that. You can right-click on a resource and select Save from the context menu.

Comment: Tried, it doesn't. It just shows them as a string `System.Byte[]`.