# Whats the difference between .Resx and .Resources file types?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I've got a lot of .resources files, that I need to open up and view. I downloaded [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/) but it only works with .Resx files. Is there a difference? Can I open .Resources files and extract its contents?

Comment: It is very unlikely that you can simply use the resources in a .resources file.  They are protected by copyright, you'll need to obtain a license from the owner to use them in your own app.  Who then won't hesitate to give you the original content.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653679/how-can-i-extract-images-from-the-resources-file-created-by-a-decompile-of-a-n

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think `resx` file contains the `non-compiled` resources in XML based format. These `resx` files are compiled into `.resource` file. So `.resource` file contains `resx` data in `binary` format.

According to MSDN

> The .resx (XML-based resource format) files are converted in to common
>   language runtime binary .resources files that can be embedded in a
>   runtime binary executable or compiled into satellite assemblies.

Answer (score 21):

You could always use the resgen.exe utility from visual studio to convert them into .resx files (the opposite of what happens during compilation):

```
resgen.exe /compile input.resources,output.resx
```

Resgen is often found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\ResGen.exe, or directly accessible from the VS command prompt.