# Delphi: How to generate the .resx from the .bdsproj

Tags: delphi

I am challenged with creating an automated release for a legacy Delphi (Delphi 2006) project.

I am a complete Delphi noob. So my question is maybe heading in a wrong direction ...

As far as I understood the release process of the given project it works like this:

- A developer opens the project in Delphi Studio
- Right-Click on the Project -> Properties -> Version Info
- He sets the new version number of the next release in the Dialog.
- He saves the project. This automatically generates the corresponding .resx file which contains the version number in binary form.
- The .bsproj and the the .resx are checked in into source control
- The automated build (Hudson) picks up the change and builds the release.

I would like to automate this process, since there are several projects that needs to get a new version number for each release.

I guess I could easily manipulate the .bsproj with a custom tool since it is xml.

However I am struggling with the generation of the .resx file which is currently done when saving the project in Delphi Studio.

Is there a way to automate the generation of the .resx? i.e. with a commandline-tool or something similar?

Or is there a smarter approach?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: .res or .resx? Personally I create a .rc file with the version info and compile the resource with brcc32.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782584/62576 might help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in a batch file

1. Update the version numbers as specified in this SO question: [change version number at build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243942/change-version-number-at-build-time)
2. Use the DCC command-line compiler to build all the projects. There's plenty of documentation for that, basically you do just `dcc32 <project>.dpr`

[DCC is e.g. documented here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler) [or here](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_from_Commandline)

I do wonder where your .resx files come from, but they can be converted as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953067/whats-the-difference-between-resx-and-resources-file-types) SO post.

Give it a go using these resources and for specific issues write a new SO question with your attempts so far.