# View content of a .resource file

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering

I have a .NET executable and I need to view the resources attached to it. I extracted `.resource` file from .NET executable using *DotNetResourcesExtract* utility but I don't now how to view content of `.resource` file.

Could someone explain how to view this file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you're using it correctly...

Assuming your storing images there.

You can simply do:

Image resfile = ProjectName.Properties.Resources.resourceName;

So if resfile is an image, you can put it into an Image control.

so, if you have an image control on your form you can simply do:
imageControl.Image = ProjectName.Properties.Resources.resourceName;

If it's a text file or any other type of file - again, you can access it the same way.  If it's a binary file, the ProjectName.Properties.Resources.resourceName will be a byte array, so you 'll need to load it in the correct manner.

Is that what you're wanting?  Otherwise indicate what type of file are you trying to extract from your resource file.

Comment: I don't have source of the .net executable . I'm interested in extracting data from .resource file using some utilities.

Answer (score 1):

> According to MSDN The .resx (XML-based resource format) files are
>   converted into common language runtime binary **.resources** files
>   that can be embedded in a runtime binary executable or compiled into
>   satellite assemblies.

**Getting to the point: How to view this?**
Well, Since it's a binary file which contains resource(images etc.) therefore you could always use Windows resources editing/extracting applications.
eg. [Restorator](http://www.bome.com/products/restorator#overview), [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to name a few.

Meanwhile, have look at this [Stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653679/how-can-i-extract-images-from-the-resources-file-created-by-a-decompile-of-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) which sound almost similar.