# How to view a resource file made with ResourceWriter()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have tested some code that generates a resource file:

```
// Creates a resource writer.
  IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("myResources.resources");

  // Adds resources to the resource writer.
  writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");

  writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");

  writer.AddResource("String 3", "Third String");

  // Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
  writer.Close();
```

How can I view what is saved in the file? Is there any resource viewer that I can use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'view'? Simply looking at the content, or being able to use it in your program?

Comment: The file is not a text file. if I open it in visual studio it shows the file in hexadecimal format + ASCII.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7653679/302248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use `Resgen.exe` which comes with Visual Studio Tools (after VS 2010).

Open up Developer Command Prompt and then you can convert your `.resources` file to a bunch of different file types, including `.txt`.

`C:\>resgen myResources.resources myResources.txt`

Will convert it into a `.txt` file.

With one caveat though;

> Conversion to `.txt` fails if file contains non-string resources (including file links)

[More info here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/resgen-exe-resource-file-generator)

Comment: Using `resgen` to convert the `.resources` file to `.resx` allows Visual Studio to load and view the resulting `.resx` file.  OP wasn't clear in his question - maybe this is what he's looking for.  (For some reason, VS throws an error if it tries to load the original `.resources` file.)

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons yeah it wasn't clear, and since he/she mentioned not being able to open in a text editor I thought the requirement was specifically to open up in text editors. I didn't try loading the `.resources` file though.

Comment: I just wanted to check if the name and value ended up in the file :-)